# Are multi-crew operations in a single-pilot aircraft counted towards ATPL requirements?

Tags: easa-regulations

I thought that you had to perform all your ATPL multi-crew time in aircraft with a certificated minimum of 2 crew, but I've heard of some pilots using time in single-pilot aircraft towards their EASA ATPL licence. Is this true? If so, could someone explain how is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the UK CAA](http://www.caa.co.uk/application.aspx?catid=2725&pagetype=65&appid=54&mode=detail&appproc=63) you need:

> 500 hours in multi-pilot **operations** on aeroplanes;

Notice that it does not say anything about the **aircraft** being multi-pilot/certified for two crew members.

An air carrier can specify in their ops manuals that, for their operations, they require a particular airplane to be operated with two crew members even if it is only type certificated for one crew member.  If their manual is approved, then it is now a "multi-pilot operation" regardless of the type-certification status of the airplane.